# Electric Heating Pad Voltage Issue with STC1000

Tags: voltage, temperature, heat, pad

I have bought an electric heating pad from [here](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1481). It works fine if I connect both legs to a power supply directly. However, I would need to connect it to a temperature controller ([STC1000](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Y7L33JQ)) for my own application, where I need to regulate and maintain the temperature of a solution.

The problem arises when I try to connect it to the heating terminal of the STC1000. For some reasons, it just does not heat up. The STC1000 I use has 24VDC (maximum rating) as the input. I have supplied 15V (actually varied from 10 V - 24 V) to it and measured the output of the heating terminal (without heating pad), and it works fine. But the moment I connect the heating pad, there is no voltage across the heating terminal/heating pad (even up to its maximum rating). A very quick circuit is shown here:

[image]

I have also tried connecting the heating pad to an Arduino Uno, straight into the GND and one of the digital pins (pin 10). It is supposed to output a 5V from the pin but when I measure the voltage across the heating pad, it is around 0.4 V. Can anyone provide some solutions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The STC1000 should only be powered by 12V.

The description of the heating pad says "Apply 5-12VDC ..." and it states the power requirements are "5V DC up to 1A".

This suggests that when using 24V the heating pad could draw nearly 5A. What is the current capability of your 24V power supply?

Simplify your set-up so you can figure out what's working and what isn't.

- Power the STC1000 from 12V
- Use a separate low-voltage power supply to power the heating pad -- like 5V.

Then determine if the STC1000 is closing the relay contacts. If that's working then you can determine what kind of the power supply you need for the heating pad.

> I have also tried connecting the heating pad to an Arduino Uno, straight into the GND and one of the digital pins (pin 10). It is supposed to output a 5V from the pin but when I measure the voltage across the heating pad, it is around 0.4 V.

An Arduino GPIO pin can only supply like 30 mA which isn't enough for the heating pad.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Apologies for I have inserted the wrong link for the STC1000. I actually bought a 24V STC1000. The link has been updated. The current capability of my power supply is 3A. I did as you suggested, but the problem still persists. I suspect somehow there is a short-circuit because the power supply turns on and off repetitively when the heating pad was connected via the STC1000. If the heating pad is connected directly to the power supply, this problem isn't there. The resistance of the heating pad is 6 Ohms when not connected.

Comment: I also realize that the relay for the heating terminal of STC1000 only closes when the input voltage is greater than 15V. And, the heating pad itself works fine. Just that when connected via STC1000, the whole thing seems to go haywire.

Comment: 24V / 6 ohms = 4 amps. I bet power supply is shutting down from an over-current situation when the heating pad is put into the circuit. I would use a lower voltage power supply for the heating pad -- lower voltage means less current drawn by the pad. Or get another heating pad and put the two in series. More resistance also means less current drawn.

Comment: I've lowered the voltage supply to 12V, giving a current of 2 amps. Still, the relay on the STC1000 automatically opens even when the state is in "heat" condition when the pad is connected. I've also connected resistors in series to the pad, the circuit works fine, but the pad does not heat up. Guess I'll try again and see if I can get something out. Thanks for replying tho!